# Adding Specific Types for Objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an object modeled as such:

```
public versionConfiguration = {
    VersionOne: {
        textOne: "textOne"
    },
    VersionTwo: {
        textOne: "textOne"
    }
};
```

Is there a way to, using TypeScript, give this a specific type? Might it be better to create a custom interface to use?

Comment: `public versionConfiguration: Configuration = { ...`

Answer (score 1):

If `versionConfiguration` a variable, it can be used as a type:

```
let foo: typeof versionConfiguration;
```

This won't work if the object is class property like in original post. In this case `interface` or `type` should be defined.

Comment: is it possible to say that an object should foollow a certain type, no matter how many keys are entered? Instead of creating an interface with every `key: type` possible, can I do something like, "for any number of keys in this object, they should all be of type `key: string` ?

Comment: It's `{ [key: string]: any }`. It's not advisable to do that for objects that aren't supposed to be really free-form, because this eliminates type safety for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill for this small example, but complete if you actually want something fancier:

```
interface Version {
  textOne: "textOne" | "textTwo";
}

interface VersionConfiguration {
  VersionOne: Version;
  VersionTwo: Version;
}
```

Since you've mentioned this is a version configuration, I used an example of a [string literal union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). This is only appropriate if you know what possible values `textOne` may take ahead of time.

Otherwise, just implement

```
interface Version {
  textOne: string;
}
```